# Redireccionamiento laravel vue broadcasting

Tags: laravel, vue.js, router, broadcast

Quisiera saber si a alguien se le ocurre como puedo solucionar el siguiente inconveniente que estoy teniendo.

Tengo una vista de perfil de administrador que valida en tiempo real con broadcasting y eventos unos datos.

Por otro lado la vista a validar donde el usuario espera esa autorización.

Al validar los datos la vista del usuario debe ser redirigida a otra vista y la del perfil administrador debe permanecer sin ningún redireccionamiento.

El problema es que ambas vistas son redirigidas a través del objet mounted de vuejs. No comprendo por que hace esto si mounted sólo está en la vista del usuario no en el perfil administrador.

Admin Controller

```
public function cambiarEstado($estado, $id){
    Acceso::where('id', $id)->update(['estado' => $estado]);

    //Usamos broadcast
    $message = 'Usuario verificado!';
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    event (new ChatEvent ($message, $user));

    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

Vue usuario

```
mounted(){
    Echo.private('my-chat')
    .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
        window.location.href = '/mails';
    });
}
```

EDITADO:
Vue Admin

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Validador</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">N°</th>
                          <th scope="col">Instagram</th>
                          <th scope="col">email</th>
                          <th scope="col">celular</th>
                          <th scope="col">codigo</th>
                          {{-- <th scope="col">estado</th> --}}
                          <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                          <th scope="col">Cambio de Estado</th>
                          <th scope="col">Fecha</th>

                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <?php $i=1; ?>
                        @foreach($datos as $usuario)

                        <tr>
                          <td>{{$i++}}</td>
                          <td>{{ $usuario->user->IdInstagram }}</td>
                          <td>{{ $usuario->email }}</td>
                          <td>{{ $usuario->celular }}</td>
                          <td>{{ $usuario->codigo }}</td>
                          {{-- <td>{{ $usuario->estado }}</td> --}}

                            @if($usuario->estado == '1')
                              <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-primary">Aprobado</span></td>
                            @else
                              <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-secondary">Desaprobado</span></td>
                            @endif

                            <td>
                              <a href="/cambiarEstado/1/{{$usuario->id}}"><span class="badge badge-primary">APROBAR</span></a>
                              <a href="/cambiarEstado/2/{{$usuario->id}}"><span class="badge badge-danger">DESAPROBAR</span></a>
                            </td>

                          <td>{{ $usuario->created_at}}</td>


                        </tr>

                        @endforeach
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

EDITADO:

VUE VIEW

```
validarCodigo: function(){

        var url = '/acceso';
        axios.post(url, {
            usuario_id: this.usuario_id,
            email: this.email,
            celular: this.celular,
            codigo: this.codigo,
            estado: this.estado
        });

        if(this.estado == '2')
            $("#ocultaEstado").css("display", "block");
        else{
            $("#ocultaEstado").css("display", "none");
        }
    }
```

El problema es ese las dos vistas son redireccionadas a la dirección mails. ¿Que podría hacer para solucionarlo?

Agradezco mucho el tiempo invertido en leer mi consulta. Toda sugerencia es bienvenida

Comment: Puedes mostrar el vue del admin, porfavor

Comment: Hola @JonathanOrta agregue lo que me solicitaste. Muchas gracias. Preguntame cualquier cosa.

Comment: En la edición solo se ven componentes de blade pero no de vue, puedes completarlo?

Comment: Hola @JonathanOrta ahí agregué lo que faltaba de vue. Muchas gracias